# I can't find a way to properly loop this hangman code

Tags: python, loops

the code I have is;

```
from random import *

name = input('Please enter your name.')
print ('Welcome,' + name, ', make sure to only enter one letter at a time while guessing. Have fun =] ')

words = ['tree', 'secret', 'tester', 'paper']



v=0
guesses = []
word = words[randint(0, 3)]
wording = list(word)


progress = list('-' * len(word))
print(progress)
print ('start guessing!')
guess=input()
guesses.append(guess)



    
def gaps():
        global wording, guesses, progress
        if len(wording) != len(guesses):
                for i in range(len(wording)): 
                        if wording[i] in guesses:
                                wording[i] = progress[i]
                                progress[i] = guesses
                        else:
                                pass
                    
def loop():
    global gaps, v

    while v<7:
            if [i for i, j in zip(wording, guesses) if i==j]:
                print('You win!')
            elif [i for i, j in zip(wording, guesses) if i!=j]:
               gaps()
               v+=1
  
loop()
print(progress)
```

I've been trying to get the code to keep repeating this bit;

```
if [i for i, j in zip(wording, guesses) if i==j]:
                print('You win!')
            elif [i for i, j in zip(wording, guesses) if i!=j]:
               gaps()
```

while asking for the user input until either the tries reach seven, or the words are the same, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: are you sure that you can do an if on a comprehension ?

Comment: @user3732793 this is a perfectly valid (if a little odd-looking) construction, but I don't think it's doing what the OP thinks it's doing. This if basically a roundabout way of checking whether _any_ elements in one list appear at the same index of the other. If none match, then the list will be empty, and `if []:` returns `False`